# In Scala, what's the most idiomatic way to name the case class equivalent of an ORM class?

Tags: scala, lift

I have to work with Lift's Mapper (I know there might be better ORMs for Scala, but this is not something I have the power to change right now). Typically, with Mapper, a table is defined this way:

```
package com.sample.model

import net.liftweb.mapper._

class Table extends LongKeyedMapper[Table] with IdPK {
  def getSingleton = Table

  object other_table_id extends MappedLongForeignKey(this, OtherTable)
  object date_field extends MappedDate(this)
  object string_field extends MappedString(this, 255)

  def toCaseClass = ...
}

object Table extends Table with LongKeyedMetaMapper[Table]
```

Now I'd like to define a case class for Table to manipulate the records more easily, as Mapper is not very "Scala-idiomatic", not very type-safe, and definitely not immutable. My case class would look like this:

```
case class TableCC(id: Long, otherTableId: Long, dateField: Option[Date], ...) {
  def toMapper = ...
}
```

How should I name the case class and where should I put it?

1. In com.sample.model with a different name (TableCC or TableCaseClass)?
2. In a different packagge (e.g. com.sample.model.caseclass) with the same name (Table)?
3. In the Table object?
4. ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I know you said that you cannot use another ORM but there are case class based ORM's for scala which work very well. (Slick works basically like this, and so do a few others)

Personally if you are going to going to use this case class as the main way to manipulate the domain I would put them all in there own package. That way if you are manuliplating the domain, you can do a

```
import com.sample.model.caseclass._
```

A few points to note:

Do not name it the same thing as the case class, this becomes confusing and I guarantee at some point you will want to use both the classes in the same file in which case you will have to alias one of them.

I would use naming like Table and TableCC. This way in your IDE you can easily find one or the other.